# Panning two stack panels in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, panning

I'm pretty new at programming for Windows Phone and so I decided to code a simple app which should only show some data.
Now I wanted to implement a pan gesture: I have two stack panels, one is displayed and with a swipe to the right, the second one Comes in (e.g. like the Whats App emoji menu).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of samples. Try [this one](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Control_animation_while_navigating_between_panes_inside_a_Windows_Phone_page) with using DragDelta and DragCompleted events.